# Error with Cheerio on Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, cheerio

i'm trying to parse code with cheerio and request on Node Js, and i'm getting error `undefined`i've been checked this, that's not request error it's cheerio
here part of my parse code.

```
            const options = Object.assign({
      url: buildUrl(opts),
      followAllRedirects: true
    }, opts.requestOptions);

    request(options, opts.throttle)
    .then(cheerio.load)
    .then(parseFields)
    .then(function (app) {
      resolve(app);
    })
    .catch(reject);
  });
}
 function parseFields ($) {

const h2 = $('faq_cat').attr('id')

const fields = {
  h2
};
```

what i'm trying to parse

```
              <div class="faq_cat" id="faq_box_faq2">
```

Thanks everybody !)

[image: error screenshot]

Express server app code :

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

var gplay = require('google-play-scraper');

gplay.download({downloadId: 'air.com.helloair.HELLOFROG',
nameid: 'digital-world-digimons'})
  .then(console.log, console.log);

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'))
```

[image: consolelog]

with console.log(h2)
[image: with console.log(h2)]

code screen
[image: code]

with console.log($.html());

[image: console.log($.html());]
 screen work!
[image]

Comment: where are you getting `undefined`? whats the full error message?

Comment: in node js command line (command prompt on Windows)

Comment: thats full error massage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is missing a `.`

Right now you are looking for a tag called `faq_cat`, which does not exist. You want to select a element with the class name `faq_cat`

Use `const h2 = $('.faq_cat').attr('id')`

Comment: @НекТраммм do you use `console.log` anywhere in your code? If so can you show that part too?

Comment: yes i'm just send console.log and code of express server app

Comment: why don't you try putting a `console.log(h2);` right after `const h2 = $('faq_cat').attr('id')` and see if it prints `faq_box_faq2`

Comment: also i can send you a site which i'm trying to parse [link](https://apkpure.com/digital-world-digimons/air.com.helloair.HELLOFROG)

Comment: are you sure you are passing the pages HTML into `cheerio.load` function?

Comment: yes ) i'm sure, from this site [link](view-source:https://apkpure.com/digital-world-digimons/air.com.helloair.HELLOFROG)

Comment: try `console.log($.html());` after `console.log(h2);` and see if it prints the html

Comment: yea, it print html

Comment: does it have the element that you want to get?

Comment: I mean, does the printed HTML in your console have the element you wanted to get? if its not there you might not be getting the html back you think you are

Comment: yes, i've found it             `<div id="faq_box">
                <div class="faq_cat" id="faq_box_faq2">
                    <dl>` i've been tried parse other elements but it still gives me same error ((

Comment: are you sure you updated `const h2 = $('.faq_cat').attr('id')` to have a `.` in front? I don't see that in your screen shot when you print `h2`

Comment: OH MY GOD !! IT WORKS !!! THANKS BRO!  God Bless You ! you are very good guy ! i've send screen of code in line !!))

Comment: but i'm stlill don't know why it doesn't work earlier ! i'm sure that i put . in front ('.faq_cat) )) whatever ) now it works !! thanks man!!